# Uninstalling and Reinstalling Node with Homebrew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, node-modules

I had previously installed node through the tools found on their website and it was giving me a warning regarding `Unbrewed header files` and listing a bunch of references to files within `/node/` directories when running `brew doctor`.

Previous to the uninstall, I was getting the following versions of node and npm:

```
$ node -v
v11.13.0
~
$ npm -v
6.11.3
```

I attempted to uninstall the existing node install by following the instructions found here:
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I then tried to reinstall node by running `brew install node` and everything went through successfully, however, when checking my node and npm versions, I am still getting a readout of the old versions referenced above. Attempting to run a brew upgrade

```
$ brew upgrade node
Warning: node 13.3.0 already installed
~
$ node -v
v11.13.0
~
$ npm -v
6.11.3
```

Could I have missed some files when uninstalling the previous version of node? Is there somewhere I am not looking?

Comment: Are you using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: I am not using nvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check where your node is installed by doing

```sh
$ which node
```

If you have a path something like **/usr/local/bin/node** try reinstalling node.

If you have a path something like **~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node** then your are running your node from nvm.

If that is the case, check if your `~/.bashrc` or your `~/.zshrc` depending on your terminal, and confirm if there are any commands that looks something like this.

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Remove these lines, and run the following command depending on your terminal.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Then check your node version again. Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: After running `which node` the following was returned:
```/Users/Matt/.nvm/versions/node/v11.13.0/bin/node```

I was not able to locate a `~/.bashrc` file but found a `~/.bash_profile` file that contains the lines that you outlined.

I attempted removing them and running `$ source ~/.bash_profile` but that returned `-bash: bash_completion: command not found`

Comment: Sure! It is too long for one comment so I will divide it into two
```
# Add `~/bin` to the `$PATH`
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH";

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
  [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && source "$file";
done;
unset file;
```

Comment: export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: Remove this section and try `source` again.

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion`

Comment: I removed those lines and ran: `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

`$ node -v
v11.13.0
~
$ npm -v
6.11.3
~
`

it looks like the node and npm versions are still the same

Comment: Can you restart your terminal? and try it again? If it doesn't change, can you confirm if `which node` changed?