# Uninstalling node with homebrew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, uninstallation, nvm

I am trying to install nvm. I already have node installed so I need to delete it to move forward but nothing I do seems to work to remove it. I installed node using homebrew. So Ive tried:
`brew uninstall node`
when I do this I get an error:
`Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node`
so I check `node -v`
and it shows `v18.6.0` so node is still there!

I found where node is installed thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309033/uninstalling-and-reinstalling-node-with-homebrew) I went to that directory and still got the same error.

Comment: What’s the output of `which node` in your shell?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: It’s obvious from that output that your statement "*I installed node using homebrew.*" is not entirely true, no? Why keep trying to uninstall it with brew if it’s not there to begin with…?

Comment: Is it this Error `No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node` telling me I didnt install node with brew? I am new to this so its not obvious just yet for me..